# antlr4 lexer rule to not match a string

Tags: java, sql, regex, antlr, antlr4

How to write an antlr4 grammar lexer rule to not match a string. For example, I have the following input string :

```
CREATE TABLE person 
( age integer,
  id integer,
  name character varying(30)),
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

Here, I need to skip those create table queries like above which contains "PRIMARY KEY" constraint.

Can we use regular expressions directly in lexer rules ?

Comment: lexer rules *are* regex, well more powerful but still regex.

Answer (score 0):

Write a couple of rules for SQLs which are required and not required.

```
goodSQL:
    'CREATE' 'TABLE' Id '('
    Id typeDef (',' Id typeDef)? ','
    ')'
;

badSQL:
    'CREATE' 'TABLE' Id '('
    Id typeDef (',' Id typeDef)? ','
    'PRIMARY' 'KEY' keyDef
    ')' ->skip
;
```

This is something to start with. You have to define `Id`, `typeDef` and `keyDef` after this. Adding `->skip` will not parse SQL statements that match the rule.

Good Luck!